# Erro ao implementar botão de login do Facebook

Tags: android, android-layout, facebook

Estou tentando implementar um botão personalizado do Facebook para login.
Mas acontece o seguinte erro:

> C:\mala_App\mala_App\mala_App\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_new_login.xml
>   Error:(117) No resource identifier found for attribute 'login_text' in
>   package 'mala.mala_app'
>   C:\mala_App\mala_App\mala_App\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_new_login.xml
>   Error:(117) No resource identifier found for attribute 'logout_text'
>   in package 'mala.mala_app' Error:(117) No resource identifier found
>   for attribute 'login_text' in package 'mala.mala_app' Error:(117) No
>   resource identifier found for attribute 'logout_text' in package
>   'mala.mala_app'

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/fundo_1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context="mala.mala_app.activity.NewLoginActivity">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_new_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fundo_1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logobranca" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:background="@color/accent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_new_login_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_titlle_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="@string/txt_email_title_login"
                android:textColor="@color/branco"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_subtitlle_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="@string/txt_sub_login"
                android:textColor="@color/branco"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="@string/txt_new_email"
                android:textColor="@color/branco"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/StyledTilEditText">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:hint="@string/type_your_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:text="@string/btn_next"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:background="#D3D3D3"/>
            <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
                xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                fb:login_text="Sign in with Facebook"
                fb:logout_text="Sign in with Facebook"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na hora de declarar o seu botão do Facebook, tem alguns pequenos erros:

Esse é o seu:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
     xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     fb:login_text="Sign in with Facebook"
     fb:logout_text="Sign in with Facebook" />
```

Assim seria da forma correta:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
     xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     fb:com_facebook_login_text="Sign in with Facebook" />
```

Tente compilar novamente dessa forma.

Comment: Obrigado, tinha visto uma resposta com estes 2 texts e o coloquei e deu este problema, mas, deixando somente o login, deu certo sim!